# GRUB2 and Foreign Keyboards

Tags: keyboard, grub2, grub-legacy

If I have GRUB2 installed on a system that is using a foreign keyboard and I want to use CLI Mode, what key would I press? On Latin-based keyboards, we would press "C", but other alphabets lack the symbol "C". Is there a special GRUB documentation page for foreign keyboards? Are older forms of GRUB the same (GRUB Legacy)?

Comment: Latin is foreign to most people in this world. What keyboard are you using/do you have problems with?

Comment: @Timo I am wanting to know how I can figure out which button to press. I do not have a specific keyboard in mind. The main reasons I ask are because #1 curiosity and #2 just in case I come across a situation like that.

Answer (score 1):

The grub manual describes the [limitations](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Platform-limitations.html) caused by platforms and that GRUB only uses  AT keyboards. I am not aware of any keyboards for foreign languages that do not also support basic ASCII.

All European seem to do so, even if specific characters are not used in a language (except for foreign words). [Spanish keyboards](http://www.wesleyan.edu/CTWMellon/graphics/spankey.jpg) have <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd> that were not in the [Spanish alphabet originally](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080103163520AAhxC1A).

Even [Japanese](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/jp106.jpg) and [Korean](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/lk201-k.gif) do have ASCII characters. So do [Thai](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6d/Thai_Keyboard_closeup.jpg/800px-Thai_Keyboard_closeup.jpg), and [Traditional Chinese](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Keyboard_layout_Chinese_Traditional.png).

Even the simple foreign keyboards used in the USA have all of these characters (maybe because A in ASCII stands for USA and not all of of the North and South America continents), although those keyboards have some keys at different location than I was used to.

Although that all is not a proof, I feel safe to say that any keyboard AT style keyboard for all definitions of "foreign" will allow you to use `grub`.
You might have some problems with non-AT style steno keyboards:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Foreign keyboards have Latin letters on them. So, I can still press "C" which on a Greek keyboard would also be "Ψ".

[image: Greek Keyboard]

Image from http://aramedia.com/kb-fireflygreek.jpg

Comment: The actual property that matters is the scancode sent, which is a property that exist far further down the chain than having "Latin letters" used (which key sends which scancode is is a property of the keyboard class, not the characters imbued on its keys).